# Percentage of total in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Sorry I am new to Crystal
I am trying to create a percentage in the report footer to show the percentage of rows that are between a certain time range.

This is a column from my data:

```
 7/17/22  9:04 
 7/16/22  13:42 
 7/17/22  9:26 
 7/17/22  9:42 
 7/16/22  11:27 
 7/17/22  9:37 
 7/17/22  9:12 
 7/17/22  12:31 
 7/17/22  9:33 
 7/17/22  13:34
```

I need to find the percentage of times that are before 10:00
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To do a conditional count, one option is to create a Running Total with a condition.

An even better option is to create a formula that returns 1 if the record matches the condition and 0 otherwise. Then, simply SUM that formula.  Note this is a SUM, not Count.